# Как объединить вложенности массива

Tags: php, массивы

Как я могу объединить вложенности массива? Имеется следующий массив:

```
Array
(
    [ingredients] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ingredient_name] => Тесто для горячих роллов п/ф
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ingredient_name] => Темпура  мука
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ingredient_name] => Нори
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ingredient_name] => Васаби
                )

        )

)
```

Результат должен быть следующим:

```
[ingredient_name] => Тесто для горячих роллов п/ф, Темпура  мука, Нори, Васаби
```

Comment: Вы там все что ли тестовое задание какое-то делаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с помощью `array_map`:

```
$array = [ 
    'ingredients' => [ 
        ['ingredient_name' => 'Тесто для горячих роллов п/ф'], 
        ['ingredient_name' => 'Темпура мука'], 
        ['ingredient_name' => 'Нори'], 
        ['ingredient_name' => 'Васаби'] 
    ] 
];

$array['ingredients'] = [
    'ingredient_name' => implode(', ', array_map(function($row) {
        return $row['ingredient_name'];
    }, $array['ingredients']))
];

print_r($array);
```

В результате получаем следующий массив:

```
Array
(
    [ingredients] => Array
        (
            [ingredient_name] => Тесто для горячих роллов п/ф, Темпура мука, Нори, Васаби
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ingredient_name = '';
foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) {
    $ingredient_name .= $ingredient['ingredient_name']
}
echo $ingredient_name;
```

Comment: Проверьте свой код внимательнее :)